# Lightspeed retail POS integration with Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, integration

Does anyone know of a plugin to integrate [Lightspeed retail](https://www.lightspeedhq.com/) and Craft Commerce?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a plugin that does this integration and a quick Google and Plugin Store search isn't coming up with anything, so it looks like it would need to be custom developed.